# Is there any way to remove subtitle's black background on IPHONE?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, jwplayer

I have video with track element for subtitles in .vtt format. I'm using JW Player 7 and this player gives opportunity to configure your subtitle styles (such as color,background,font,etc...).

But on iphone (here video plays within iphone's native player and styled subtitles aren't showing here, here you see actual track element's cue) I have issue with removing background and border radius of subtitle. You can see that black background and border radius [***HERE***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfenN.jpg)

I have searched in google many times but can't find any example where subtitle has no background. I found one solution from IOS Settings. But I want to remove it from my side if it is possible (via jquery or javascript).

Please help me to get rid of this background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution.

I used plugin which is described [**HERE**](http://dev.powered-by-haiku.co.uk/solutions/jwioscaptions/). This plugin saved me. Also I changed windowColor to white and opacity value to 0. And my subtitles are without that black background. Hope this will help others.